# Cypress: Code in page object file is being executed as a test case before the before hook

Tags: cypress

I was trying to use a condition as a function within a page object.

```
class Folders {

    DropdownCheckFunction(){   
        cy.get('.more-less-container').then((dropdown) => {
        if(dropdown.find('.name').contains('More')){
            cy.get('more-less-container').click()
        }
        else{
            console.log('folders are in expanded state')
        }
    })

}    

    Drafts(){
        this.DropdownCheckFunction()
        cy.get('.category-content').find('[title="Drafts"]').click()
          .get(".folder-details").should('contain.text', 'Drafts')
    }
```

Issue here is that the page object is getting executed as a test case and is happening before the code in BEFORE hook is being run. Below is the test file code

```
describe('Testing all cases related to Drafts', () => {
    
    before(() => {
        cy.login()
      })
    })


it('Needs to open the Drafts folder', () => {
        openFolder.Drafts()
    });
```

Attaching the error seen on the test runner for reference

[image: Image showing the Error on the test runner]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is bad formatting.

If you line up your code, you can see it - your test is outside the scope of the `before()`.

```js
describe('Testing all cases related to Drafts', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.login()
  })
})         // move this bracket to below the `it()`


it ('Needs to open the Drafts folder', () => {
  openFolder.Drafts()
});
```

Comment: Right! I totally missed that. 
Thanks! :)